# Using Sequoyah Localization for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, string, plugins, localization

I'm interested in the powerful Sequoyah tool to localize my strings. The tool is easily downloaded and installed under Eclipse, but infortunately I don't know how to automatic translate columns.
The user interface have a field "Translator" (when right-click on the spritesheet) with an empty list from witch one should choose the translator tool. I supposed it would refer to Google Translator but I'm not able to use it.
Anyone knows Sequoyah and could explain how to?

Comment: I posted an answer on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966070/translator-service-in-sequoyah-plugin-of-eclipse/